# mysql_real_escape_string not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

My mysql_real_escape_string is being ignored. It's killing me, because I feel like it's something tiny that I'm missing.

The $htmlText variable comes from a TinyMCE editor where the text is rendered as HTML i.e. with tags etc.

```
<?php 
    /*--------GLOBAL PROCEDURES--------*/
    session_start();
    require "../scr/config-data.php.inc";
    mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die 
    ("Could Not Connect".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Could Not Connect".mysql_error());

    /*-----SEVERAL SELECT/INSERT QUERIES, ALL WORKING FINE-----*/

    /*--------SPECIFIC PROCEDURES-------*/      
    if($_POST['submit']){
        //Check that POS has been chosen
        $htmlText = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cust']);
        if($htmlText != ""){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES(NULL, '$htmlText' )") or die(mysql_error());
        }else{
            $feedback = "Please Enter some text into the editor";
        }
    }

    /*--------CLOSING PROCEDURES-------*/
    mysql_close();

?>
```

The strange thing is, it's been adapted from a script that works, only changing the variable names. I'm getting an Error in MySQL syntax. It's also not escaping the HTML in the text so I'm getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order VALUES(NULL, '

sfgafgafs

')' at line 1
```

Comment: What error message do you get for what example input?

Comment: the above error message is given, but the particular field should be <p>sfgafgafs</p> when escaped, but it's rendering it as HTML

Comment: Is your table named "order" ?  Try changing that to ``order`` (backticks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the error message given by you it looks like you are using `order` as the table name which happens to be a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Try enclosing it in back ticks.

Comment: Thanks! I did this about a week ago with the word add... Didn't learn from my own mistakes by the looks of things, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

mysql_real_escape_string will not escape any html. It only escapes \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

Your table's name should not be "order", because it is an SQL special word. You should rename it or make sure that you put it in backticks.

Comment: no, it's order but I changed it to table just for the example, to take it out of the context. But luckily, when I pasted my error message I'd left the word Order in, it's a reserved word :( thanks anyway!

Comment: `table` is also a reserved word BTW

Answer (score 2):

I too believe the reason is due to the table name being 'order', as mysql takes it like you are trying to use the order clause in an insert query, change the table name to something else..

Comment: the accepted answer said that over 2 months ago. I backticked the table name and it worked. Thanks for the effort, but your a little late for this one

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your missing the Link Identifier?

string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier ] )

Comment: You do know that the link identifier is optional right?  "If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used."

Comment: I thought it was required, next time ill just post comments so i dont lose any points!